# How to prevent my new shoes charging me?

Tags: comfort, electricity

I got already a few ideas from [How can I avoid getting static shocks in the winter?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/281/10538) .

But I think my question is still diferent in the solution being asked for, as a) I am well aware of what causes the charging up and b) for me it would also work, if instead of reducing the shock I could prevent charging up in the first place.

So I have a new pair of shoes. Since I wear them, I get very easily electrical charged. Especially if walking on carpetfloors. I was hoping this will get less, after the shoes start being worn a little, but it didn't stop yet for 3 weeks. After having had a walk of like 50 meters on the hallways at work, I get almost assured a shock, when ever I have to touch a doorhandle. What is quite often the case, and the shocks I am getting are sometimes as painful, that it is even when touching metal with my arm through clothes very unpleasant. Not to mention how much it sometimes hurt at the finger tips...

So are there any modifications I could do to the shoes<sup>1</sup> or myself to prevent charging up?

And if not so, is there any item, I could use to discharge myself in a comfortable way in a work setting? Even the walk to the Watercooler requires me to touch 3 different doorhandles leaving alone the water cooler it self having metal buttons... And it feels unhandy for me having my carkeys with me every time I have to go somewhere as I usually lock them away while at work.
But if there was an item being more handy for this setting, that would work too.

---

<sup>1</sup>rubber sole with some synthetic threading forming the shoes cover.

Comment: Did you tried shoes cover made of Polypropylene? It is very inexpensive, widely available and durable to use.

Comment: I believe that if you could create an electrical connection between your foot and the floor, the built-up charge would constantly release itself. That is, run a wire or piece of metal from the inside of the shoe down to the floor. I'm not sure how to do this without poking a hole through your shoe, which would let in water.